# failed to add service - already in use error

Tags: embedded, opengl

I compiled SFML library and my app on Raspbian with this tutorial https://github.com/oomek/sfml-pi. After this I moved shared objects and app to buildroot system for Raspberry Pi 4. I chosed `DISPMANX` version, my goal was to run app without X server.

When I try to run app, I have error `failed to add service - already in use?`. I know that there was many similar topics, I tried this solutions:

1. Comment `dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d` in `config.txt` -> this line didn't existed in my config.
2. Change `gpu_mem` to `128` -> any improvement

My `config.txt`:

```
# Please note that this is only a sample, we recommend you to change it to fit
# your needs.
# You should override this file using a post-build script.
# See http://buildroot.org/manual.html#rootfs-custom
# and http://elinux.org/RPiconfig for a description of config.txt syntax

# We always use the same names, the real used variant is selected by
# BR2_PACKAGE_RPI_FIRMWARE_{DEFAULT,X,CD} choice
start_file=start.elf
fixup_file=fixup.dat

kernel=zImage

# To use an external initramfs file
#initramfs rootfs.cpio.gz

# Disable overscan assuming the display supports displaying the full resolution
# If the text shown on the screen disappears off the edge, comment this out
disable_overscan=1

# How much memory in MB to assign to the GPU on Pi models having
# 256, 512 or 1024 MB total memory
gpu_mem_256=128
gpu_mem_512=128
gpu_mem_1024=128
gpu_mem_1024=192
gpu_mem=128

# fixes rpi (3B, 3B+, 3A+, 4B and Zero W) ttyAMA0 serial console
dtoverlay=miniuart-bt
```

On buildroot I set `opengl` from `gst1-plugins-base` with `dispmanx`, `gles2`, `egl` and `wayland`. I didn't set `mesa-3d`.

Any idea how can I make my app working? Should I add something to my `config.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. I'm not sure if it is still actual to you but if yes, these steps was working for me.

1. You only need mesa3d and inside mesa3d select v3d and vc4
2. In the config.txt add

> dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

Once you boot your pi:

3. modprobe vc4
4. modprobe v3d

also after it please make sure that

> /dev/dri/card0

is present

Comment: have you done it with Pi 4? I ended with thought that it may be impossible on Pi 4 and works only on Pi 0-3

Comment: Yes, PI4. It was a stressful time, but I managed to do it. The only difference I'm using SDL2 and not SFML

Comment: I hope to test your solution in free time. Although it is not necessary for me right now, I'm curious if it works :D